# Shortcode won't take into account custom post ID put in parameter

Tags: shortcode

I wrote a little custom shortcode and when I try to use it in a custom post it won't take into account the parameter I set up.

**What it's supposed to do**

The shortcode is supposed to take a custom post ID into parameter and display a div that use the thumbnail of this post as a background if there's one, and then display the title of the post inside that DIV. Pretty simple stuff.

**What it does**

In front the shortcode appears to work as intended but don't take ID parameter into account and use current post ID to execute the function instead. The weird thing is that when I put a default value "4075" for $ID in the array it works fine. It just won't take the parameter into account when I set it with `[lire-aussi ID="4075"]`

**The code**

```php
function shortcode_lire_aussi( $atts ){
        extract(
          shortcode_atts( array(
          'ID' => '',
        ), $atts));
    
        
          $title= get_the_title($ID);
          $linkURL= get_permalink($ID);
    
          if(has_post_thumbnail($ID)){
            $background = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $ID );
            $output= '
            <div style = "background-image : url('.$background.');">
              <p>
                <a href="'.$linkURL.'">'.$title.'</a>
              </p>
          </div>';
          }
          else{
            $output= '
          <div style = "background-color : black;">
            <p>
              <a href="'.$linkURL.'">'.$title.'</a>
            </p>
          </div>';
          }
    
    
            return $output;
        
       
     
}
    
add_shortcode('lire-aussi', 'shortcode_lire_aussi');
```

I'm not really familiar with PHP and my knowledge of that language is very limited, I'm clearly missing something but can't figure what.

Answer (score 0):

Shortcode attributes should be all lowercase

### A Note on Security

There are 2 major security issues in your shortcode:

1. `extract` is dangerous as it can overwrite variables, it would be much safer to use `$ID = ! empty( $atts['ID'] ) ? $atts['ID'] : null;` instead. You might see this in a lot of examples but this is because copy pasting is popular and people are unaware, not because it's ok. Never use `extract()` under any circumstances if you value security and safety.
2. There is no escaping on your variables, when you output values you should escape dynamic values, e.g. `<a href="'.$linkURL.'">` should be `<a href="'.esc_url( $linkURL ).'">`. This *guarantees* that only a URL can go in the `href` part, even if something malicious is inserted that tries to break out.

Comment: Thx for the tips and the security heads up ! But any of this solved my issue :/ 
The shortcode still us the current post despite putting an ID as parameter. And now it even won't show the background image :p

Comment: so it's not that it doesn't show the background image, it's that it shows the wrong background image?

Comment: have you tried using something other than `ID` as the parameter name? Can you eliminate the background and have it just return the `$ID` so that you can verify that it's correctly getting that value? _Are you still using the `extract` function?_

Comment: when I use my shortcode [lire-aussi ID="4075"] in the content of a cutom post, in front it should display a div with the thumbnail of this ID in background and the related title. But instead it shows the current post info, as if the parameter used in [lire-aussi ID="4075"] is not taken into acount.
Then again, when the value 4075 is put as a default value for 'ID' in the array it works.

Comment: yes I already understood that part, but if you instead make it output the ID directly in the shortcode does it output the ID you expected? And if you change ID to something else that is not named ID does that help? _Also are you still using the extract function?_ Ignore the background and focus on the ID value, your background code looks fine, that is not where the issue comes from. Don't infer or assume the value based on the background, print out out so you can see it directly and report back the results, and get rid of the `extract` call, I suspect the problem is there.

Comment: I tryed not to use extract() but as I said, I'm not very familiar with PHP and I didn't really underdstand the piece of code you gave me :

$ID = ! empty( $atts['ID'] ) ? $atts['ID'] : null;

Comment: Looks like I solved the main issue ( the shortcode not fetching the right ID put as parameter) by renaming the variable inside the atts array. Apparantly it should always be in lower case: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_atts/

Comment: @FabienBertrand-Durousset can you post that as a new answer? I'd like to upvote it. As for my code snippet, it's a direct replacement for the extract call.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I solved the main issue ( the shortcode not fetching the right ID put as parameter) by renaming the variable inside the atts array. Apparantly it should always be in lower case: developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_atts